# Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability while finalizing an operation

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, startup, stateless

I'm getting many errors like a timeout awaiting for service container stability and IllegalStateException becaus component is stopped but I'm not sure what is provoking this misperformance

My project consist of three modules an ear, an ejb and an war, and ejb has beans.xml on resources/META-INF and war has beans.xml in WEB-INF.

Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back.

**Code**

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class StartupShutdownBean {

    @Inject
    SysUserService sUserSvc;

    @PostConstruct
    private void startup() {
        sUserSvc.cleanUpSessions(); //save dateEnd of open sessions in db
    }

    @PreDestroy
    private void shutdown() {
        sUserSvc.cleanUpSessions();
    }
}
```

**Error summary**

```
12:38:15,724 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Interceptor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 122) WELD-001703: Unable to determine the @Intercepted Bean<?> for [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Intercepted private com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.interceptedBean
...
12:38:34,310 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0348: Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back. Step that first updated the service container was 'full-replace-deployment' at address '[]'
12:38:34,636 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 123) WFLYEE0006: Failed to destroy component instance org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponentInstance@2c7a4d23: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0043: Component is stopped
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0043: Component is stopped
...
12:38:39,331 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentHandlerUtil$4@1be19bac for operation {"operation" => "full-replace-deployment","address" => [],"name" => "ada-ear.ear","content" => [{"archive" => false,"path" => "deployments/ada-ear.ear","relative-to" => "jboss.server.base.dir"}],"persistent" => false,"owner" => [("subsystem" => "deployment-scanner"),("scanner" => "default")],"enabled" => true,"runtime-name" => undefined} at address [] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
...
12:38:44,337 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0349: Timeout after [5] seconds waiting for service container stability while finalizing an operation. Process must be restarted. Step that first updated the service container was 'full-replace-deployment' at address '[]'
12:38:54,519 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 9) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("read-attribute") failed - address: ([...
```

**Error trace complete**

```
12:38:15,724 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Interceptor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 122) WELD-001703: Unable to determine the @Intercepted Bean<?> for [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Intercepted private com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.interceptedBean
12:38:15,857 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 122) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.13.SP1 20160303-1204 for context '/ada'
12:38:34,310 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0348: Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back. Step that first updated the service container was 'full-replace-deployment' at address '[]'
12:38:34,636 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 123) WFLYEE0006: Failed to destroy component instance org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponentInstance@2c7a4d23: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0043: Component is stopped
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:187)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.requiresNew(CMTTxInterceptor.java:349)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponentInstance.destroy(BasicComponentInstance.java:125)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.destroySingletonInstance(SingletonComponent.java:197)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.done(SingletonComponent.java:144)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.EJBComponent.stop(EJBComponent.java:553)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$2.run(ComponentStartService.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0043: Component is stopped
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.waitForComponentStart(BasicComponent.java:110)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:194)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at es.imas.ada.business.logging.boundary.SysUserService$$$view95.cleanUpSessions(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:433)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:128)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:67)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
    at es.imas.ada.business.logging.boundary.SysUserService$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.cleanUpSessions(Unknown Source)
    at es.imas.ada.business.StartupShutdownBean.shutdown(StartupShutdownBean.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doLifecycleInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:114)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceReleaseInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceReleaseInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
    ... 24 more

12:38:39,331 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentHandlerUtil$4@1be19bac for operation {"operation" => "full-replace-deployment","address" => [],"name" => "ada-ear.ear","content" => [{"archive" => false,"path" => "deployments/ada-ear.ear","relative-to" => "jboss.server.base.dir"}],"persistent" => false,"owner" => [("subsystem" => "deployment-scanner"),("scanner" => "default")],"enabled" => true,"runtime-name" => undefined} at address [] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:498)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1369)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1328)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1301)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$300(AbstractOperationContext.java:1185)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeResultHandlerPhase(AbstractOperationContext.java:767)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:644)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:370)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1329)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:400)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:222)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$3$1$1.run(ModelControllerImpl.java:756)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$3$1$1.run(ModelControllerImpl.java:750)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$3$1.run(ModelControllerImpl.java:750)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

12:38:44,337 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0349: Timeout after [5] seconds waiting for service container stability while finalizing an operation. Process must be restarted. Step that first updated the service container was 'full-replace-deployment' at address '[]'
12:38:54,519 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 9) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("read-attribute") failed - address: ([...
```